# Adding / Removing TableRows Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

In my activity, I have a TableLayout where TableRows are added dynamically.

This is done in a for loop like so...

```
        for(i = 0; i < orderArray.length(); i++)
        {
            getSaleData(i);

            //build the TextView's for each row...      
            txtItemName = new TextView(this);
            itemNames.add(txtItemName);
            txtItemName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
            txtItemName.setTextSize(15);
            txtItemName.setMaxLines(1);
            txtItemName.setId(i);
            txtItemName.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);

            edtItemQty = new EditText(this); 
            edits.add(edtItemQty);
            edtItemQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            edtItemQty.setTextSize(15);
            edtItemQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            itemNames.get(i).setText(currentItem);
            edits.get(i).setText(itemQuantity);

            //alternate between line colors depending on the flag
            if(lineColor)
            {
                itemNames.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(LINE_COLOR));
                edits.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(LINE_COLOR));
                lineColor = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lineColor = true;
            }

            //create a new TableRow and add the TextViews
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.addView(itemNames.get(i));
            row.addView(edits.get(i));

            //add row to the table layout
            tblItems.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

A resulting example looks like this...

[image]

Could you please advise on how I would go about removing these rows dynamically?

Thanks

EDIT: Decided to go with a longClickListener

Here is the full code I ended up using...

```
longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener()
{
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{
    //get the row
    final TableRow row = (TableRow)tblItems.findViewWithTag(v.getTag());

    //confirm the deletion first...
    final AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(TransactionEdit.this);
    confirm.setIcon(R.drawable.warningicon);
    confirm.setTitle("Remove Item?");
    confirm.setMessage("Remove this item from the the order?");
    confirm.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //find the matching row in the List
            for(int j = 0; j < edits.size(); j ++)
            {
                //tags contain a prefix and a number e.g. qty5 (Same with rows)
                String qtyIndex = edits.get(j).getTag().toString().replace("qty", "");
                String rowIndex = row.getTag().toString().replace("row", "");

                //if its the same one...
                if(qtyIndex.equals(rowIndex))
                {
                    //...set the text to 0 to flag as not to be include...
                    edits.get(j).setText((CharSequence)"0");
                    break;
                }
            }                   
            //...then hide the row
            row.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
        }
    });
    confirm.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    confirm.show();
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Decide what you need to remove, find where in the table the rows are located, and remove them from the table.

Comment: Is there any specific need that you are using `TableRow` structure instead `List`?

Comment: @RaviBhatt I have added a screenshot to show you an example of what I want the table to look like... hope this helps

Comment: @LouisEvans on which event you want to remove that row?

Comment: @RaviBhatt I am not to sure...I was thinking of maybe having a "X" button on the same row? But I have no idea about how to remove the rows using the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemNames.remove(txtItemName);
edits.remove(edtItemQty);
```

or if you know the index

```
edits.remove(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest that you give tag to your row and 'x' button runtime while adding it into main layout.
The 'id' you provide should be relative like "row1" for table row and "1" for the 'x' button of row 1. You are using loop here so `row.setTag("row"+i)` for the row and `closeButton.setTag(i)` would do that.
Create a common listener for 'x' button, and get the tag of it. Filter the number from the tag, and remove or make the visibility of row gone having the same tag number id.

Some thing like :

```
private View.OnClickListener commonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button closeButton = (Button) v;
            TableRow r = (TableRow)layout.findViewWithTag("row"+closeButton.getTag());
            r.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Just for reference that You can set tag of close button like "closeButton1" as well but in that case you need to separate the text "closeButton" and "1" to get which button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response...however, I cannot use the finViewByTag(). It says "The method findViewByTag(Object) is undefined for the type R.layout"

Comment: @LouisEvans sorry, the method is `findViewWithTag` and not the findViewByTag. Have edited the answer check with that.

Comment: @LouisEvans Did you find the success or any issues?

Comment: I did this a bit differently but it works now, thanks! I didn't know you could use tags as well as IDs, so that's something useful I have learned

Comment: @LouisEvans okay its good that you got the solution. It would be great if you post your working code as answer here, so some other user having same problem can use it. :)